# Validate Google Re-Captcha Server Side (Sandboxed solution)

Tags: sandbox-solution, validation

I tried validate google recaptcha at server side, and according it's documentation, I had to do a request to an address (https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify), passing three parameters (secret, response and remoteip).

I used the WebRequest class to make this request so I could get the validation response but I received an error (Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed)

I looked up other forums and it seems that sandboxed solutions, specifically do not allow requests to external websites and it screwed me because I wanted to put this solution on Office365. I searched on the web and I didn't find a valid solution that uses re-captcha to post information on forms.

Does anyone here knows how can I validate re-captcha at server side? Is there some configuration that I must do so I can finally, get the validation response?

Comment: Only if you do it in an autohosted or provider hosted app. You will not be able to run server side code on office 365 (including sandboxed solutions with code)

Comment: Is it difficult to make this?
What is this autohosted or provider hosted app?

Comment: [MSDN explains it well](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179930(v=office.15).aspx) but effectively, they are sites hosted on non SharePoint servers, with own code (with basically whatever language you want), that do the things you want.